# Why isnt the copy constructor of member class called?

Tags: c++, copy-constructor

```
class member
{
public:
    member()
    {
       cout<<"Calling member constr"<<'\n';
    }
    member(const member&)
    {
        cout<<"Calling member copy constr"<<'\n';
    }
};

class fred
{
public:
    fred()
    {
        cout<<"calling fred constr"<<'\n';
    }
    fred(const fred &)
    {
        cout<<"Calling fred copy constr"<<'\n';
    }
protected:
    member member_;
};

int main()
{
    fred a;
    fred b=a;
}

Output:
Calling member constr
calling fred constr
**Calling member constr**
Calling fred copy constr
```

Comment: A common case where you _don't_ want to copy a member in a copy ctor is the pimpl idiom. There you want to copy the _implementation_, not the _pointer_ to it. Ideally, either _all_ class members have useful copy semantics) and the class itself doesn't need a copy ctor, or none of the class members do. In the latter case, you write your own copy ctor, and it's good that no members are copied by default.

Answer (score 16):

Because you did not call `member`'s copy constructor. You need to copy the members explicitly if you override the default copy constructor of `fred`.

```
fred(const fred& other) : member_(other.member_) {
    cout<<"Calling fred copy constr"<<'\n';
}
```

Answer (score 6):

It isn't called because you explicitly asked the compiler not to call it. When you defined your own copy constructor for class `fred`, you essentially told the compiler that you wanted to take matters into your hands and do the copying yourself. Since you do nothing to copy the `member_` in the `fred`'s copy constructor, it isn't copied.

If you get rid of the explicit definition of `fred`'s copy constructor, the compiler will provide an implicit one for you, which will call the `member`'s copy constructor to copy `member_`.

If you insist on defining `fred`'s copy constructor yourself, you have to copy `member_` yourself, as KennyTM suggested.

Answer (score 0):

If class A has a class B member and you explicitly implement the copy ctor for class A, then you must explicitly copy the members there, in this case call the B copy ctor, otherwise the B member will be default constructed, not copy constructed.

Answer (score 0):

You have to explicitly call it in this case. Because, you have overloaded constructors.

Btw, When I see "Fred", it reminds me this useful resource, please have look for further understanding of C++ constructors: http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/ctors.html